# SQL Parameter not working in Select .... Like statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
public ActionResult GetExamNameSuggestion(string prefix)
{
   //Its not working
   string sql = "Select Top 5 ExamName From Qualifications Where ExamName Like '%@ExamName%'";

   //Its working
   string sql = "Select Top 5 ExamName From Qualifications Where ExamName Like '%S%'";

   SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter("@ExamName",SqlDbType.VarChar,50){Value=prefix}};
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Please tag dbms used! (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: What do you means by not working. Please specify?

Comment: Please include your actual code - we can't see where you create the SQLConnection, SQLCommand or apply the parameters to the command - there might be a mistake there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate wildcard:

```
string sql = "Select Top 5 ExamName From Qualifications Where ExamName Like '%' + @ExamName + '%'";
```

If you use **SQL Server 2012+** use:

```
string sql = "Select Top 5 ExamName From Qualifications Where ExamName Like CONCAT('%', @ExamName, '%')";
```

Using: `'%@ExamName%'` you search for exact string. I guess you don't have value in column = `'%@ExamName%'`

*Warning:*

1. Keep in mind that `%phrase%` is not SARG-able so query optimizer won't use index on that column (if exists any).
2. Using `TOP` without explicit `ORDER BY` may return different results between multiple executions.